# How do I show error message separately in angular js in mvc cshtml page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implemented server side validation in mvc project.

controller code

```
   return Json(ListErrors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

create.js

```
     .error(function (responseText, status, error) {
                                $scope.errorvalue = false;
                                $scope.errors = responseText;
   $('#txtname').addClass('errorClass');
                $scope.name = responseText;
                    $scope.namealert = true;
                            });
```

In responseText I'm getting list of errors with `property name` and `error message` ,
[image]

How can I bind `error message` to different `labels` based on `property name`?

If property name is `Name` then error message should be `please enter name`
for `name` input textbox

I tried like following but it gives all object value :(

```
  <input id="txtname" type=text ng-model="Name" class="form-control">
  <label ng-model="name" ng-show="namealert" style="color:red;margin-top:-35px">{{name}}</label>
```

output

```
[{"PropertyName":"Name","ErrorMessage":"Please enter Namename","AttemptedValue":null,"CustomState":null,"ErrorCode":null,"FormattedMessageArguments":null,"FormattedMessagePlaceholderValues":null}]
```

Comment: Why don't you use an ng-repeat over responseText (which seems to be an object and not a string/text, so the variable name is a bit off) or extract the first items error message using `responseText[0].ErrorMessage`?

Comment: I'm very new to angular and I want to extract error messages using `propertyName` I'm confused how Name textbox can bind `Name ` property error message?

Comment: What do you mean with "using propertyName"? What value do you expect to be in your input, and why, and where does it come from?

Comment: Btw, your `<label>` should have the `for` attribute to refer to your input, `<label for="txtname"></label>` if you want them to be related to each other

Comment: I mean to say if I have two input one is for `Name` other is for `Description` now When I got two errors like `please enter name` and `please enter description` I should apply name error to name textbox. and description error message to description textbox but i;m failed to display messages with different textbox I can display all messages at one place using `MyErrors in errors` thats is `   $scope.errors = responseText;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are close.  You have your JSON that contains the key/value pairs that you would like to bind.  In your controller parse the JSON to get the values out and set the value you get out to a property on the viewmodal that you have bind to a label control.

Here is a website with an example:  https://ujjaini.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/binding-json-data-to-front-end-angular-js-framework/

Comment: Read this to learn more on binding:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808257/Part-Data-Binding-In-AngularJS

Comment: thanks how may I convert it in my above code if possible jsfiddle will be helpful as i;m new to angular thanks :)